# Div won't center horizontally

Tags: css

Here is the code. This is as simple as can be. Why won't it center?

```
.msg {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="msg">This is not centered. Why not?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All you're trying to do is place this `<div>` at the center of the page?

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, is that the only css on the page? (I don't see a starting style tag)

Answer (score 1):

It needs to have `position: relative;`, plus the parent element also needs to have a position setting other than `static` (which is the default).